# How to avoid Cross Origin problem when trying to use ArcGIS Online Geocode server?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, geocoding

I'm trying to use a javascript locator object with a geocode server of ArcGIS Online: http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Locators/ESRI_Geocode_EU/GeocodeServer

When I call the method `locator.addressToLocations(options)`, I get the cross-origin problem.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: which browsers did you test on?

Comment: Mozilla FF 34.0 and Google Chrome 39.0

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in the header for [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/exp_cors_buffer.html) sample, when the server you are making calls to actually supports CORS, you can notify the JSAPI like this.

`esriConfig.defaults.io.corsEnabledServers.push("server.com")`

that being said, i don't think sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com supports CORS, so i'd recommend using our production [World Geocoding Service](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-find-address-candidates.htm) instead.

in situations where you must work with a server that doesn't support CORS, or need to support browsers that don't support CORS, you'll have to configure a [proxy](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/ags_proxy.html) and reference it in your application.